# my flutter app icon is not showing on phone apps list

Tags: flutter

I had created the default(counter) app from flutter and this works perfectly in terms of appearing on the app list as an icon just like any other normal app. However, as i continue adding files to it for example plugins, added firebase too, I rebuild it and the app launches but the app icon does not show on the app list on the phone.
Now am wondering if this is a bug on flutter sdk or what has happened. Since previously I was using flutter version 2.2.2 and now am on flutter 2.5.0

Comment: did you try flutter clean ? this happen on real device ? did you try on emulator ? Some phone allow to delete an app from main screen but keep the app in application folder.

Comment: I did try flutter clean and no change. Haven't tried on an emulator though. Also, I have gone to settings found the app and uninstalled it then rebuilt and still nothing. It is not my first flutter and this is definitely a new issue that I have not experienced before

Comment: Try delete pubspec.lock, android and ios folder then execute "flutter create -i swift -a kotlin", i think you move something in android manifest by adding firebase inside. You should reconfigure firebase in it after. I did not encounter bugs with flutter 2.5.0, but i already got some bugs with firebase configuration.

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Comment: That project was taken over by someone else (non-flutter) but I have been creating other projects later and this is not an issue anymore. Current Flutter version 2.10.3

Comment: Actually I figured it out and posted an answer to this old question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out I think. The problem is in the android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml. I believe you need to include the following tag in your intent-filters:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

However, I had some tags overwriting this one and this is what broke the visibility in the app drawer. My intent filters now look as follows and everything is working now:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <!-- <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> -->
            <!-- <data android:scheme="my.test.app" /> -->
        </intent-filter>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what if we need to use <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> and <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

Comment: I honestly don't know, I figured this out by accident.

Answer (score 4):

The manifest you provided has an `<intent-filter>` that combines both the intent to be launched from the home screen (launcher) and the intent to be accessed via a custom URL scheme.

The issue here is that you're combining both functionalities into a single `<intent-filter>`. Android might be interpreting this intent filter as if it's only meant to handle the custom URL scheme and not as an app that should also appear on the home screen.

To fix this, you should separate these two purposes into two distinct `<intent-filter>`s. Here's how you can do it:

```
<activity ...>
    <!-- Intent filter for launching the app from the launcher -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    
    <!-- Intent filter for handling the custom URL scheme -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="appname" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I came across your answer because, first of all, it looks like it might been written or assisted by an AI such as ChatGPT. If that's the case, I encourage you to delete it quickly, since [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).  But even more confusing is that your answer references *"[t]he manifest you provided"*, when no manifest was in the question.  That makes me think that this answer is some confusion on the part of an AI based on a combination of the question and the answer. Is there another explanation? Thanks!

Comment: AI or not, this helped me figure out how to get my app to appear in the launcher again. In addition its better than the solution I was getting from AI myself.